# Construct char arrays within function

Tags: esp8266, programming

I'm pretty new to C++ / Arduino code, please bear with me. Following code currently gives me a `Exception (28): epc1=0x40201287 epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000`.

I *suspect* that this is because I'm trying to use the pointer to a local variable `char parsedString` in `drawMenu()` which is probably destroyed after running `renderMenu()` and therefor I get a memory related exception(?). Is that correct?

Secondly, if that is true, I'm wondering if I'm just simply trying too hard to avoid global variables, I already got a ton. And creating for every single parsing variable in a function sounds like overkill. What would be the most efficient way to render my menu?

```
void drawMenu () {
  
  char* lines;
  renderMenu(lines);

  for (int i = 0; i < menuMaxLines; i++) {
    Serial.println(lines[i]);
  }
}

void renderMenu(char* &output) {

  // Get current menu items
  MenuItem * menuCurrentItems = getMenuItems();

  // Loop out the menu items at the current position (menuPosition), don't exceed the count of menuitems (menuCurrentItemCount) and don't exceed more then the desired lines (menuMaxLines)
  for (int i = menuPosition; i < menuCurrentItemCount && i < menuPosition + menuMaxLines; i++) {
    
    MenuItem menuItem = menuCurrentItems[i];
    char parsedString[menuMaxLines];

    // Prefix for the menulabel, when focussed
    if (menuFocussedItem == i) {
      strcat(parsedString, "> ");
    }
    else {
      strcat(parsedString, "  ");
    }

    char output[i - menuPosition][menuMaxWidth];
    strcpy(output[i - menuPosition], parsedString); 
  }
}
```

Comment: In `renderMenu()` you are trying to create an array with the name `output` (which would hide the parameter of the function) with a variable size. That cannot work. Arrays created like this need sizes known at compile time. Otherwise you would need to use dynamic allocation (using `new`). Why aren't you just creating a simple char array inside of `drawMenu()`?

Comment: Also: because of the parameter of `renderMenu()` is hidden, the pointer `lines` is never set to anything valid. Thus printing the elements of it means reading from invalid memory location. There is just no array allocated behind that pointer

Comment: @chrisl, gcc can create an array on stack with a variable for size.

Comment: Thanks @chrisl, I value your help. I keep forgetting that arrays need to have a fixed size. So your saying that your first comment could be fixed by using `char* lines[menuMaxLines]` in `drawMenu()`? And your second question, I first trying to make that array of char arrays in the function but I was unable to return that and therefor went with the out var. Are you able to provide me with a solution to that?

Comment: @juraj, you assumed correctly. It’s a `const int`